# VeeValidate 3.x get specific classes from ValidationProvider by name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm using Vee Validte 3.x in my Nuxt JS/Vue project. I need to be able to get the classes from a particular Validation Provider element by it's name or some unique identifier and output the classes object somewhere else on my page.

I'm struggling to figure out how, and thought a `ref` would work but didn't.

Here's my code:

```html
<!-- Data Source (Table) (Validation Workaround) -->
<validation-provider
  tag="div"
  name="data source"
  :rules="{ required: { allowFalse: false } }"
  v-slot="{ errors, classes }"
>
  <CustomInput
    class="hidden-spans"
    :options="editor.sources"
    v-model="mockedCheckboxes.source.isChecked" />
  <span class="block text-xs text-red-500 mt-1">{{ errors[0] }}</span>mockedCheckboxes.source.classes = classes" />
</validation-provider>
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
this.$validator('data source').classes
```

Somewhere in my Vue file so that I can use the classes from one input elsewhere, this isn't working though.

Comment: `this.$validator` will not be used in the same component but somewhere else in your app, right ?

Comment: Correct, it will be used in my page and not the component

Answer (score 0):

`this.$validator` was actually removed in favor of `ValidationObserver`: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/migration.html#migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0

So far, if you try to validate something that is not directly in the component you're working on, you should watch the flags of the validation (`errors`) and update the status on a Vuex store. Then access Vuex back to decide if the input is valid and proceed further.

There is no global validation to my knowledge.